# React: How to frequently update a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-state

I am trying to display a width of an svg rectangle (using the svgdot.js library). I have a listener on the rectangle resize:

```
   rect.on('resizing', function (event: any) {
      self.setState({width: rect.width(), height: rect.height()});
    });
```

However, this triggers, ofcourse, a state update verry frequently. Though I have a verry simple UI, the page becomes verry laggy.

Is there a more efficient way where I can realtime update the state or a variable without the UI becoming slow?

Comment: It kind of depends on what you need the `width` and `hight` for. You might only want to update after resize ended or also at some points in between. Are there any visual changes to your ui that have to be shown while the rect is being resized?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [debouncing or throttling](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

> Debouncing enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in “execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called.”

> Throttling enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called over time. As in “execute this function at most once every 100 milliseconds.”

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

rect.on(
  "resizing",
  debounce(function (event: any) {
    this.setState({ width: rect.width(), height: rect.height() });
  }, 1000)
);
```

Comment: In case of resizing it might also be useful to call it based on the difference between the start size and the current resized size, defining a threshold so to say. It depends on the use case. E.g. called every 20px but not more often than every 200ms but at least once.